# What do charismatic Christians actually mean by the phrase "tonight is an open heaven"?

Tags: terminology, charismatic

I have heard this phrase bandied around for about the last 10-15 years and I am wondering how it originated and if it has any scriptural basis.

My own belief is that in the light of the cross and the finished work of Christ, it is always an open heaven and God is always accessible everywhere.

Comment: where have you heard it? can you give further context?

Comment: I have heard it used in Anglican renewal meetings, non affiliated charismatic meetings and also in mainstream Pentecostal meetings.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Sorry, usually in the context of end of meeting "ministry" times., i.e. "Tonight is an open heaven, a special anointing, the Spirit is here, come and be healed, come and be set free" etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a term used to describe  the revelation of something the Holy Spirit showed them in a dream or a word of knowledge.

Comment: As I thought then, sort of spiritual fake news, as it's always an open heaven because of the cross. God is always there for us, not just special times or places.

Comment: @ColinAmey Anyone can claim there is an 'open heaven' above their own particular meeting or gathering. But the heavens were opened only above Christ himself.

Comment: Can you please [edit] this to provide some references to quotes to support your answer?